# git workflow for deployment of code to production, when there is a need to change debugging related code in production?

Tags: git, debugging, branching-and-merging, git-flow, branching-strategy

We use git with the [git flow](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow) branching model for our project. In our codebase there is some debugging related code which we turn on by default in non-production code (debugging output / debugging flags).

Our current workflow for deploying a release to production (master branch) is to create a release branch off of our development code base (develop branch). On the release branch we disable debugging features (debugging flags), test, eventually make changes after testing, commit, push the release to master, merge master back to develop and change the debugging flags back on manually.

Is there a better workflow than setting debugging flags on and off manually when releasing and merging back to develop?

Edit on 24/01/16:
In reply to @Lazureus comment:
The used languages are: Python (backend). And Javascript (frontend). No makefile is used, because there is nothing to build. The IDE we're using for python is pycharm.

Comment: What is the language of your project ? and are you using makefile or maybe cmake? or maybe some other IDE project managment ?

Comment: @Lazureus: See edit of question.